# Abstract Inheritance in Django Model, causing MAX recursion depth error

Tags: django, inheritance, recursion, depth

I'm trying to implement abstract inheritance in Django with the following code, but it produces a MAX recursion depth error. I'm trying to override a model's `save` method.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #i'm doing something here

        #i think the problem is in the return statement specifically because of the
        #self.__class__ expression.
        return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    p = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

produces this error (end of the trace, it's lengthy):

```
  File "/home/jultra/ap3w/jultra_01/mysite/testsite/models.py", line 10, in save
    return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jultra/ap3w/jultra_01/mysite/testsite/models.py", line 10, in save
    return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jultra/ap3w/jultra_01/mysite/testsite/models.py", line 10, in save
    return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jultra/ap3w/jultra_01/mysite/testsite/models.py", line 10, in save
    return super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `self.__class__` by `BaseModel`? By the way, you don't need the `return` because `save` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do **not** call `super` on `self.__class__`! Call it on the actual class:

```
return super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is because `self.__class__` always refers to the actual concrete class of the instance. So if you inherit `MyModel` from `BaseModel`, when you get to the `save` method in `BaseModel` `self.__class__` is still `MyModel`. So it finds the super of MyModel, which is BaseModel, so calls the save in BaseModel, which once again finds the super of MyModel...

Comment: The "Model" classes "save" does not return anything!