# Django abstract parent model save overriding

Tags: django, django-models, slug

I'm trying to write an abstract parent model in Django which will help me making some *slug* field from *name* field for many other child models. It uses *trans* encoding which works perfect for translitterating form cyrillic to latin letters. Then it uses slugify function from django to remove garbage.

```
class SlugModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=u'')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            slug = slugify(unicode(self.name).encode('trans'))
        else:
            slug = self.slug
        count = self.__class__.objects.filter(slug = slug).count()
        if count > 1:
            if slug[-2]=='_':
                count = int(slug[-1])
                slug = slug[:-2]
            self.slug = '{0}_{1}'.format(slug,count+1)
        else:
            self.slug = slug
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class Foo(SlugModel):
    pass
```

The problem occurs when I'm trying to save some Foo object: it causes RuntimeError (maximum recursion depth exceeded). What am I doing wrong? How do I write `super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` correctly?

Comment: Check out this question (a duplicate) for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948132/abstract-inheritance-in-django-model-causing-max-recursion-depth-error

Comment: That thread does not have a good answer.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I got it. Instead of using  `super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

I needed  `super(SlugModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

Thanks to peppergrower.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`.